# how to use send method to add a name and age to this generator

Tags: python-3.x, generator

I am currently working on a python course and I'm having difficulty with this step. How can I solve this?

Here is the code I've done so far and the screenshots of the task and the step im stuck on. also, we use a txt file which ill screenshot and put which we use as the argument "**guest_list.txt**" in the generator instantiation. the goal of this step is to use the **.send()** method in the generator to add a name and age to the generator and yield the name and add the info to the guests dictionary

[image: the step ive completed]
[image: the step im stuck on]
[image: the txt file we put as the argument]

```
guests = {}


def read_guestlist(file_name):
  text_file = open(file_name,'r')
  while True:
    line_data = text_file.readline().strip().split(",")
    if len(line_data) < 2:
    # If no more lines, close file
      text_file.close()
      break
    name = line_data[0]
    age = int(line_data[1])
    guests[name] = age
    yield name
    

guestlist_gen = read_guestlist("guest_list.txt")

maxi = 9
count = 0

for one in guestlist_gen:
  print(one)
  if count == maxi:
    guestlist_gen.close()
  else:
    count += 1
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i want to use the .send() method to send "Jane, 35" to be processed by the generator with the data from the .txt file , and hence add the value to the guests dictionary through the generator